# I want to read a Json and return all the 'OP' that have the same 'TANK' (I'M USING NODE). Follow the example

Tags: node.js, json

I HAVE THIS JSON IN MY CODE...

```
let  data = [
  { OP: '8800', tank: '1' }, 
  { OP: '8801', tank: '1' }, 
  { OP: '8802', tank: '1' },
  { OP: '8803', tank: '1' },
  { OP: '8804', tank: '2' },
  { OP: '8805', tank: '2' },
  { OP: '8806', tank: '2' }
```

> AND I WANT TO RETURN THIS...

```
[
  { OP: '8800', tank: '1' }, 
  { OP: '8801', tank: '1' }, 
  { OP: '8802', tank: '1' },
  { OP: '8803', tank: '1' },
]
[
  { OP: '8804', tank: '2' },
  { OP: '8805', tank: '2' },
  { OP: '8806', tank: '2' },
]
```

> I WOULD LIKE THAT YOU SHOW ME THE BEST WAY TO APPLY THIS FUNCTION.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```js
const data = [
  { OP: "8800", tank: "1" },
  { OP: "8801", tank: "1" },
  { OP: "8802", tank: "1" },
  { OP: "8803", tank: "1" },
  { OP: "8804", tank: "2" },
  { OP: "8805", tank: "2" },
  { OP: "8806", tank: "2" },
];

function chunkData(data) {
  const m = new Map();

  for (const record of data) {
    const { tank } = record;

    if (!m.has(tank)) {
      m.set(tank, []);
    }

    m.get(tank).push(record);
  }

  return [...m.values()];
}

console.log(chunkData(data));
```

Comment: Hi there. If you found my answer helpful, please accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function f1(data){
  var arr=[]
  var map = new Map
  data.forEach(v=>{
    if(map.has(v.tank)){
      arr[map.get(v.tank)].push(v)
    } else {
      map.set(v.tank,arr.length)
      arr[map.get(v.tank)]=[v]
    }
  })
  return arr
}

let  data = [
  { OP: '8800', tank: '1' }, 
  { OP: '8801', tank: '1' }, 
  { OP: '8802', tank: '1' },
  { OP: '8803', tank: '1' },
  { OP: '8804', tank: '2' },
  { OP: '8805', tank: '2' },
  { OP: '8806', tank: '2' }
]

console.log(f1(data))
```